# Neo4j - referring to ID() inside curly brackets

Tags: neo4j, cypher, where-clause

I have a question about Neo4j Cypher language.
Is it possible to have a WHERE-clause such as:

```
WHERE (a) -[:r]-> (:b { id: 1234 })
```

but, such that `id: 1234` actually refers to `ID()` and not "id" property?

Answer (score 0):

only if you introduced an identifier for `:b` before.

```
MATCH (a)
MATCH (b) where id(b) = 1234 and b:b
WHERE (a) -[:r]-> (b)
```

but then you can do a normal match

```
MATCH (a) -[:r]-> (b)
WHERE id(b) = 1234 and b:b
```

// the check for the label :b might be irrelevant if you already have an id